# What happens, when two threads try to access a synchronous block?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronous

What happens, when two threads try to access a synchronized block?

Will one of the threads be queued somewhere and access the thread later, or will the thread give up if the trial fails?

Comment: A thread entering a synchronized block is like a person entering a phone booth. One at a time: some wait outside while one talks. Who enters next depends on thread priority or in case of phone booth, who comes first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean a *synchronized* block, one thread will manage to acquire the monitor, and the other thread will block until the monitor is released.

See [section 14.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19) and [section 17.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-17.1) of the JLS for more details, including:

> The synchronized statement (§14.19) computes a reference to an object; it then attempts to perform a lock action on that object's monitor and **does not proceed further until the lock action has successfully completed**. After the lock action has been performed, the body of the synchronized statement is executed. If execution of the body is ever completed, either normally or abruptly, an unlock action is automatically performed on that same monitor.

(Emphasis mine.)

If you need any other semantics - e.g. timeouts - you should use one of the the types in the `java.util.concurrent.locks` package, so that you can use methods such as `tryLock()` and `tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit)`.

Answer (score 3):

> Will one of the threads be queued somewhere

Yes, It's queued in JVM and waits until runnig thread frees the lock.

> will the thread give up if the trial fails

No, it keeps on trying till JVM is alive. but not trying during while another thread in running the synchronized code.(unless a timeout is specified)

Lets say `ThreadA` and `ThreadB` are trying for a synchronized block `sb` and `ThreadB` succeeds. Now, `ThreadA` will wait till `ThreadB` finishes. in the mean time, suppose `ThreadC` comes for `sb`. it sees that the block is being run by some thread and waits in same queue with `ThreadA`. When `ThreadB` finishes either `ThreadA` or `ThreadC` is given a chance to execute.

So, technically, it's NOT a queue but a similar datastructure.

Answer (score 2):

One of them will wait, forever if necessary (such as the first thread executing an infinite loop), though that would be a rather bad design. There are no timeouts on code execution synchronisation.

From the JLS:

> A synchronized statement acquires a mutual-exclusion lock on behalf of the executing thread, executes a block, then releases the lock. While the executing thread owns the lock, **no other thread may acquire the lock.**

Answer (score 0):

If `synchronized` block is being executed by another thread then both thread will wait. Otherwise , one thread will be allowed to work upon and another will wait until first thread completes its job.